# 1 exception(s): Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid method Magento\Catalog\Block\Navigation::canShowBlock

Tags: magento2

I'm getting this error in a new Magento 2 installation when I click on a category link

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid method Magento\Catalog\Block\Navigation::canShowBlock

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Activate the Anchor option for category